# NPOI: Excel column formatted to decimal with SXSSFWorkbook?

Tags: asp.net, excel, npoi

I am developing a website with ASP.net (VS2015 C #).

I need to export a `MySql` table with a large amount of data (500000+ rows and 100 columns) to excel (`xlsx`), with format.

After trying many options, the NPOI (v 3.20) library allows this export using types that use streaming (`SXSSFWorkbook` & `SXSSFSheet`).

If I use `XSSFWorkbook` I get and Out of memory filling the rows.

With `SXSSFWorkbook` I have been able to format the `xlsx` with different fonts and colors, but I am having problems with the types of data exported:

- Date types ok
- Int types ok
- Text ok
- Decimals inputs like 100.35 --> problems, I get a text column. I need a ouput like a number 100,35.

The code I use to format the data is:

> ```
> SXSSFWorkbook wb = new SXSSFWorkbook();
> SXSSFSheet sh = (SXSSFSheet)wb.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");
> sh.SetRandomAccessWindowSize(100);
>
> ICellStyle testStyleHeader = wb.CreateCellStyle();
> ICellStyle testStyleRow = wb.CreateCellStyle();
>
> // Header Style
> testStyleHeader.FillForegroundColor = NPOI.SS.UserModel.IndexedColors.RoyalBlue.Index;
> testStyleHeader.FillPattern = FillPattern.SolidForeground;
>
> // Double style (with 2 decimals like 453.65)
> ICellStyle cellStyleDouble = wb.CreateCellStyle();
> cellStyleDouble.DataFormat = wb.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("0.00");
>
> // Font 
> XSSFFont hFontBlack = (XSSFFont)wb.CreateFont();
> hFontBlack.FontHeightInPoints = 11;
> hFontBlack.FontName = "Calibri";
> hFontBlack.Color = NPOI.SS.UserModel.IndexedColors.Black.Index;
> testStyleHeader.SetFont(hFontBlack);
>
> IRow row = sh.CreateRow(0);
> int j = 0;
> ICell cell = row.CreateCell(j);
>
> // Fill Header row
> cell.SetCellValue("XXXX"); cell.CellStyle = testeStyleHeader; j++; cell = row.CreateCell(j);
> cell.SetCellValue("YYYY"); cell.CellStyle = testeStyleHeader; j++; cell = row.CreateCell(j);
> cell.SetCellValue("ZZZZ"); cell.CellStyle = testeStyleHeader; j++; cell = row.CreateCell(j);
> cell.SetCellValue("WWWW"); cell.CellStyle = testeStyleHeader; j++; cell = row.CreateCell(j);
>
> // Fill Rows
> int i = 1; // row Number
> IRow row2; // No Header Row
> ICell cell2; // No Header cell
>
> while (dr.Read())  // dr is the DataReader
> {
>    row2 = sh.CreateRow(i);
>                                                             
>   for (int cont = 0; cont < NumColumns; cont++) 
>   {
>      if (cont == 0) // This column is a date
>      {
>        …. // code for date format
>      }
>      else if (cont == 3) // Double column with 2 decimals¡! (values samples 100.45   5654.80 etc.)
>      {
>         ICell cell3 = row2.CreateCell(j, NPOI.SS.UserModel.CellType.Numeric);
>         cell3.CellStyle = cellStyleDouble;
>         cell3.SetCellValue(Convert.ToDouble(dr[cont]));
>       }
>      else
>      {…. // code for tex format, int format etc.
>      }
>    }
>    i++;
> ```
>
> }

With this code, in the decimal column (cont ==3), I get a text column.

However, with the same code, if I declare the no streaming types:

> ```
> XSSFWorkbook wb = new XSSFWorkbook();
> XSSFSheet sh = (SSFSheet)wb.CreateSheet("Sheet 1");
> ```

Only with this changes I get a perfect numeric columnn 3...

For this line:

> cellStyleDouble.DataFormat = wb.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("0.00");

I have tried with different types:

- "#.#"
- "#,##0.000"
- "##.#"
- Etc…

In some cases I get a number, but not with the desired format.

So...streaming types do not allow this formatting?

Comment: I've got the same problem. Also, the created file is corrupted. Excel successfully recover the file's data, but decimal numbers are text (while integers are are correctly numbers)

Answer (score 1):

Just change the Culture Info to en-US

```
        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("en-Us");

        ISheet worksheet = Workbook.CreateSheet(dt.TableName);

        IRow HeaderRow = worksheet.CreateRow(0);

        for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
        {
            ICell HeaderCell = HeaderRow.CreateCell(i);

            HeaderCell.SetCellValue(dt.Columns[i].ColumnName);
        }

        for (int j = 0; j < dt.Rows.Count; j++)
        {
            IRow Row = worksheet.CreateRow(j + 1);

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Columns.Count; i++)
            {
                ICell Cell = Row.CreateCell(i);

                if (dt.Columns[i].DataType.IsOfType(typeof(decimal)) && dt.Rows[j][i] != DBNull.Value)
                {
                    Cell.SetCellType(CellType.Numeric);

                    Cell.SetCellValue((double)dt.Rows[j][i]);
                }
                else
                    Cell.SetCellValue(dt.Rows[j][i].ToString());
            }
        }

        Thread.CurrentThread.CurrentCulture = new CultureInfo("pt-Br");
```

It works for me!

Comment: It works for me too, but I can't figure out why. Can someone explain, please?

Answer (score 0):

can you try your formatting based on below code snippet. I am using this approach to format phone number.

```
XSSFCellStyle currencyCellStyle = (XSSFCellStyle)workbook.CreateCellStyle();
XSSFDataFormat currencyDataFormat = (XSSFDataFormat)workbook.CreateDataFormat();
currrencyCellStyle.SetDataFormat(currencyDataFormat.GetFormat("00000.00"));  //Formats: #####.##, 00000##.##
```

sometimes its tricky  to find exact formatting in NPOI :). Please try below approaches

```
 ICellStyle CellStyle = workbook.CreateCellStyle();
 CellStyle.DataFormat = workbook.CreateDataFormat().GetFormat("number"); // or Number
```

or

```
CellStyle cellStyle = wb.createCellStyle();
cellStyle.setDataFormat(wb.getCreationHelper().createDataFormat().getFormat("#.#")); // or #####.## or number
```

Comment: I've tried it in this way, but the column I get is a text type .... :-(

Comment: I have mentioned two more approaches. can you try them sometimes its hit and trial in NPOI to get actual output.

Comment: I've been testing all the possible combinations of these 2 forms, and I'm still getting text in the output. I think the problem is the SXSSFWorkbook & SXSSFSheet types, since with the not streamed versions  I get the correct number output. Could it be that the library did not have implemented a correct format for doubles using streaming types ?

Comment: it can have issue. you can try posing it to their forum. As per their documentation here https://poi.apache.org/apidocs/org/apache/poi/ss/usermodel/DataFormat.html suggested syntax looks correct.

Comment: I think it is possible that Java POI works with this, but NPOI it is not yet finished in this issue (number format with streamed data)...